# I am trying to execute a code and getting the error"child killed segmentation violation " and the program stopped working

Tags: tcl

on executing the following code in tcl(opensees) it is showing "child killed segmentation violation" and the program stopped working.

## Monte carlo simulation

```
set Ntrials 10000
set Nfails 0 
for {set i 1} {$i <= $Ntrials} {incr i} {

    set U '';#initialize list to Null 
    foreach rv [getRVTags] {
        set val [expr rand()]; #random float between 0 and 1
        lappend U [getStdNormalInverseCDF $val]
    }

    set X [transformUtoX $U]

    set irv 0
    foreach rv "1 2" {
        updateParameter $rv[lindex $X $irv]
        incr irv
    }
    set x1 [getParamValue 1]
    set X2 [getParamValue 2]

    set g [expr $x1*$x1-$x2*$x2];#g=R^2-S^2
    if { $g <= 0 } {
        incr Nfail
    }
}

puts "Monte Carlo Simulation, pf = [expr double($Nfail)/$Ntrials]";
```

Comment: All Tcl does is to report that a crash happened, e.g., in a process spawned from but external to Tcl: `error child killed segmentation violation`. This could be a process created using Tcl's `[exec]` or via `[open]`. I don't have access to OpenSees sources, though, so I can't provide more assistance.

Comment: Single quotes have no special meaning in Tcl: `set U ''` means "set the variable U to the 2-character string consisting of two single quotes". Presumably whatever you're doing with `$U` is upset that the first argument is that 2-character string. If you want to initialize a variable to an *empty list*, do either `set U {}` or more explicitly `set U [list]`

Comment: Also, it's good practice to [brace your expressions](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Brace+your+expr-essions)

Comment: Apart from using `''` instead of `""` and a few other likely basic syntax errors (`$rv[lindex $X $irv]` instead of `$rv [lindex $X $irv]`) there's nothing obviously wrong. Why code other than Tcl itself crashes… isn't a Tcl problem usually.